# Columns have different width than specified in styles

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup for columns:

```
<table class="b-hdfs__files-list">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-selected">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-type">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-name">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-size">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-user">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-group">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-permissions">
        <col span="1" class="b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-date">
    </colgroup>
```

And CSS:

```
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-selected {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-type {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-name {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-size {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-user {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-group {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-permissions {
  width: 50px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-date {
  width: 50px;
}
```

But although every column is equal as expected, they are not 50px wide, but 33px. I'm wondering why. Here is the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/qvvd18o0/) with complete markup and styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have given 100% width for table, it is adjusting according to it.
Hence remove `width:100%;` in `.b-hdfs__files-list`  and give `width: 100px;` (your choice) for `col`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
.b-hdfs__files-list {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try using this instead:

```
.b-hdfs__files-list {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
.b-hdfs__files-list {
  width: 100%;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list {
  width: auto;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-selected {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-type {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-name {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-size {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-user {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-group {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-permissions {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list .b-hdfs__files-list__item-property-col-width-date {
  width: 15px;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list__header {
  text-align: left;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c7d0d9;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list__item {
  line-height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c7d0d9;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list__item:hover {
  background-color: #E8F1FB;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list__item-property {
  color: #494a4c;
}
.b-hdfs__files-list__item-property__name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/qvvd18o0/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `table-layout: fixed` to your table